# Importing Numpy to Python: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: python, numpy

Importing numpy gives me the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure cold not be found.
```

Here is the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-5a0bd626bb1d>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy

  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs

  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *

  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
```

This is a fresh install of Anaconda, and I have updated numpy to the latest version. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Try to use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see where that dll is read from. Anyway, a quick solution for you would be to install the Windows binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @giosans Thanks! After yet a other uninstall/install it still didn't work. However, after replacing the numpy file with that one it works like charm!

Comment: @Dole I have the exact same issue, have uninstalled reinstalled anaconda. Also numpy but no joy. Please help there seems to me a number of numpy files what did you replace and where did you get the replacement from. Thanks a million Richard

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was in the same boat, and I managed to fix it as Rafael Monteiro said but including some other DLLs listed below:

1. mkl_core.dll
2. mkl_intel_thread.dll-
3. mkl_def
4. libiomp5md.dll

Those in were quite smaller than the ones in Python Library\bin directory so I assume those didn't have some functions defined, hence the errors while loading numpy.

I'm not sure why were those installed but it was just after a Windows Update followed by a device driver installation.

I do not think the OP would still be interested as the question is a year old but I will leave this here as it will save some time for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I had the same error here (Python 3.5 64-bit on Windows 10), and [this page](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/835) helped me find the solution. The problem was a conflict with `libiomp5md.dll`, which existed on two locations:

- C:\Windows\System32\libiomp5md.dll
- C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\libiomp5md.dll

Python was trying to use the version in System32 folder, which was an old version. I removed it (renamed) and now it uses the correct version, on Anaconda3 folder, and now I can import numpy without the import error.